# Meteor breaks after update to 0.7.1.1 Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Here is the full error I am seeing:

```
/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
  at Object.exports.parse (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/parse-stack.js:18:26)
  at Object.exception (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/buildmessage.js:355:28)
  at /Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/packages.js:495:22
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at [object Object]._.extend.build (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/packages.js:279:7)
  at /Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/packages.js:1088:13
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at [object Object]._.extend.build (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/packages.js:1087:7)
  at [object Object]._.extend.getForApp (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/library.js:285:9)
  at /Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/bundler.js:1762:25
  at Object.capture (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/buildmessage.js:191:5)
  at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/bundler.js:1697:31)
  at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/run-app.js:396:32)
  at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/run-app.js:520:28)
  at /Users/myName/.meteor/tools/8d9edffd4f/tools/run-app.js:340:12
```

Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: My guess is this is an error in your code, which looks like... ?

Comment: Sorry, my code base is large enough that I couldn't post anything meaningful. Wish the error was more specific. I'll post below with what I found was the issue.

Comment: You can trim and trim things out of the code until you reach the minimal part that still reproduces the issues. With a code base that large, you've probably done that sort of things many times already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it!

Turns out it was an error in one of my Less style files. Using an @variable that was not defined.

Seems the new updated Less compiler in Meteor 0.7.1.1 doesn't throw errors the way the old one did. Hopefully they will get error reporting to work well with the new Less compiler.

Comment: I had the same error, but it was a '<' in my html that caused the entire application to crash with 0 indication about where the problem was. It was horrific trying to debug what was causing it, as WebStorm wasn't even showing that there was a possible problem... Urgh...